# Solving double integral in polar coordinates, boundaries problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following double integral to solve:
[image]
and the region given is a 
circle equation: [image]
[image]

Could anyone explain how to get the q which is the angle of the given circle? I would write 0-2pi, but I've seen some other examples and I think that the angles are incorrect. The radius is from **0** to **-6rcos(q)** I'm 100 percent certain that this is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle should run from $q = \pi/2$ to $q=3\pi/2$.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: The region lies in the left halfplane.

Comment: i understand that but how did you conclude that, based on the equation?

Comment: Polar coordinates work by specifying points on the curve by angle and radius. There are only points on the curve for the angles specified in the answer.

Comment: Sorry but still unsure about that. I mean there is not any other criteria in the problem, for example: it doesn't say that x<=-3. Let' s say that this was included then I would have easily known that the angles are from pi/2-3pi/2

Comment: For each angle in the interval $\pi/2 \leq q \leq 3\pi/2$ the distance from the origin is given by $r = 6\cos(q)$. This is all you need to know to describe the curve that encloses the region.

Comment: It's actually r=-6cos(q) does that change anything

Comment: oh yes, that is the correct expression in the first place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44751/discussion-between-wesewx-and-user353673).

Comment: Sorry to bale, but I really need to go. We could continue at some other time unless someone else can give you a satisfactory answer.